# How google drive API authentication works

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am developing a app where I will access the Google Drive files.

According to google documentation I have to create a new project into Google Developers Console using my app's package name and a `sha1` fingerprint.

Now my question is if I create different project using same package name and `sha1` fingerprint then how will Google authenticate?

Actually if anyone can tell me how does the process work, I mean why do I need to create such a project?

Comment: this q isxtoo broad. take a look at the oauth2 docs and try to make a more specific question

Comment: Thats odd. Question is not tagged Apps-Script but shows up under its feed.

Comment: You should not be able to create multiple projects containing credentials with the same package name and sha1.

Comment: Should i able to create multiple project using the same sha1 ? @kroikie

Comment: Yes using the sha1 multiple times is ok. Using the package name and sha1 together multiple times is not.